# Router forces to use netcard's hardware mac

Tags: wifi, mac-address, spoofing

I'm trying to connect to a network that manages device connections by it's mac.
So, I want to connect a device, which has no interface to connect it properly by itself

I decided to use a different device using the adapter with mac of the device I really want to connect to enable wifi connection for it (pretty legal, as I think)

So, I use macchanger to change a mac of my wifi card (adapter) and it work's well.
Then, I'm connecting to a wifi network and after that `macchanger --show <mydevice>` shows me that my adapter's mac is a hardware mac.

I know that there are plenty of methods and services allow to detect a mac spoofing but can the network environment force to use a hardware mac-address of the device?

If so, are there any methods to prevent it and connect to a network with a spoofed mac?

Note1: Also, network detects when you are using a mac randomization on mobile device, which is usually enabled by default and asks to disable that feature to countinue authorisation.

Note2: When I connect with a spoofed mac, it changes mac "automatically" and connects well.

Comment: `can the network environment force to use a hardware mac-address of the device?` No. It's trivial to change the MAC on some platforms. It shouldn't be relied on as a security control.

Comment: @GregAskew Thank you. After some more research, found out, my OS has been doing it and there was a parameter for it in network settings. Question closed.